# A noun which means a flaw in achieving something

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, nouns

It's a single word. My explanation might be vague but I'll try my best to explain.

Basically, a person trying to achieve a goal but his _______ hinder him from attaining the said. It's sort of defect or problem (something they lack) which inevitably leads to failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more context its hard to say.  "His flaws hinder him" works in a general sense, but if you want to be more specific, context is needed.

But speaking specifically to the 'lacking' aspect - perhaps **deficiencies** is a possible answer:

From Merriam-Webster:

> : the quality or state of being defective or of lacking some necessary
>   quality or element : the quality or state of being deficient :
>   INADEQUACY

Answer (score -1):

This word doesn't fit into the sentence, but fits your other descriptions of the what you a are looking for.

> [**downfall**](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/downfall) MW
>
> 2 
>   : something that causes failure
>
> > In the end, gambling proved to be his downfall. *[=ruin, undoing]*

This refers to a specific aspect of a person/project/design/etc. that has most of the responsibility for its failure.

Typically the flaw or vice itself is described as the downfall, rather than someone "possessing" a downfall.